# How to get angulrjs value in php variable?

Tags: php, angularjs

How to get the angularjs value in PHP variable? angular value how to assign the PHP variable??
thank you advance.

Comment: You need to explain your question better

Comment: This angular value {{data.name}} , I want to assign that value one php variable., but how??

Comment: if you have a value like this on your client-side (i.e. in the browser, a variable in the JavaScript, or a field value) and you want to use that value to do something on the server then you have to send the value to the server using a HTTP request. You can do that either via a full postback, or an ajax request. Then you client-side can wait for the response from the server, and act appropriately once it gets it - perhaps the server will send back some response after it finishes processing, which can be used by the client? Maybe, I don't know the full situation, but that's the general principle

Comment: Above comments thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your angular variable in PHP like this

```
<?php
    $value = "{{ data.name }}";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value); 

?>
```

Or if you want to send parameters from a form the use $http service

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/yourUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // Handling when success 
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // Handling when error 
  });
```

And you can read more about angular $http service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: <?php
    $value = "{{ angular.variable }}";
?>          its not working .

Comment: can you pls help.

Comment: Kindly share your code to get more help from my side

Comment: This angular value {{data.name}}  , I want to assign that value one php variable., but how??

Comment: Update code please check

Comment: <?php
    $value = "{{ data.name }}";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value); 

?>  its also not working..

Comment: it's not possible ?

Comment: Its possible when you explain your problem correctly

Comment: <td>{{data.name}}</td> I want to take 'data.name' this variable in php for select query.

Comment: @Dipali see my comment above. It seems you don't understand about client- and server-side code. They run at different times, on different machines. They don't execute in sequence in the way you appear to imagine. The PHP runs first before the page even exists. It's used to _create_ the page, in fact. Any output from PHP is injected into the page as static text. You can use PHP to print Javascript and inject static values into it. Then PHP finished, and the page is delivered to the browser. Only then does the JS/Angular code run, on the user's browser.

Comment: Above comments thank you so much. Sry, I am confused about angularjs.thnkx.

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use browser cookies as an interface to send data between your angularjs code and php one:
save the value you want to send to php in a cookie variable in javascript (or angularjs) like that

```
document.cookie = "variable_name = variable_value";
```

then you can take this saved value in your php code like that:

```
$read_cookie_var = $_COOKIE['variable_name'];
```

and after you finish saving the data you wanted, don't forget to destroy the saved cookie variable in php like that:

```
unset($_COOKIE['variable_name']);
```